# How to simplify the summation of a recurrence relation

Tags: summation, algorithms, asymptotics, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

After solving the recurrence relation

$$T(n) = 3T(\frac{n}{3}) + n\log(n)$$

I get following equation

$$T(n)=3kT(\frac{n}{3k})+ n\log(n) + n\log(\frac{n}{3}) + n\log(\frac{n}{3^2})+\dots+n\log(\frac{n}{3^k})$$

I don't know how to simplify the summation and how to know the asymptotic function?

Comment: You should really learn MathJax, it's far easier than most mathematical problems. And in cases like this, try $n=3^k$, first. The resulting recurrence might be easier to solve.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and the [Meta Read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and enhance your question

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)

Comment: $$T(n)=n \left(3C-\log \left(n^{-\frac{\log (3 n)}{\log (9)}}\right)\right)$$

Comment: $T(n)=O\left(n \log ^2 n\right)$

Comment: @Raffaele Can you show me the solution step by step please ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=3^k$. We have,

$T(n)=3^kT(\frac{n}{3^k})+ n\log(n) + n\log(\frac{n}{3}) + n\log(\frac{n}{3^2})+\dots+n\log(\frac{n}{3^k})$

$=3^k.T(1)+n\log\left(n.\frac{n}{3^1}.\frac{n}{3^2}\ldots.\frac{n}{3^k}\right)$

$=3^k.1+n\log\left(n.\frac{n^k}{3^{1+2+\ldots+k}}\right)$ (since $T(1)=1$)

$=3^k+n\log\left(\frac{n^{k+1}}{3^{1+2+\ldots+k}}\right)$

$=3^k+n\log\left(\frac{(3^k)^{k+1}}{3^{k(k+1)/2}}\right)$

$=3^k+n\log\left(\frac{3^{k(k+1)}}{3^{k(k+1)/2}}\right)$

$=3^k+3^k\log\left(3^{k(k+1)/2}\right)$

$=3^k+3^k.k(k+1)/2.\log3$

$=3^k+\Theta(3^k.k^2)$

$=\Theta(3^k.k^2)$

$=\Theta(n.(\log n)^2)$ (since $n=3^k$)

Or use [Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)):

$T(n) = 3T(\frac{n}{3}) + n\log(n)$, here $c_{crit}=\log_b a = \log_3 3 = 1$, $k=1$, hence, we have,

$T(n) = \Theta(n^{c_{crit}}\log^{k+1}n)=\Theta(n\log^2 n)$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $\log n = \ln n$ we have

$$
T\left(3^{\log_3 n}\right)=3T\left(3^{\log_3 \left(\frac n3\right)}\right)+n\frac{\log_3 n}{\log_3 e}
$$

now calling $\mathcal{T}(\cdot)=T\left(3^{(\cdot)}\right)$ and $z = \log_3 n$ we follow with the recurrence

$$
\mathcal{T}(z)= 3 \mathcal{T}(z-1)+z3^z c_0
$$

with solution

$$
\mathcal{T}(z)= 3^{z-1}c_1+z(z+1)3^z\frac{c_0}{2}
$$

and now going backwards with $z = \log_3 n$ we arrive at

$$
T(n) = \frac n3 c_1 +n(\log_3 n) (1+\log_3 n)\frac {c_0}{2}
$$

NOTE

The recurrence $\mathcal{T}(z)= 3 \mathcal{T}(z-1)+z3^z c_0 $ is linear so the solution can be composed as $\mathcal{T}(z)=\mathcal{T}_h(z)+\mathcal{T}_p(z)$. The homogeneous solution is direct

$$
\mathcal{T}_h(z) = 3^{z-1}c_1
$$

now taking as particular $\mathcal{T}_p(z) = 3^{z-1}c_1(z)$ and substituting into the complete recurrence we get

$$
c_1(z) = c_1(z-1)+3z c_0
$$

hence

$$
c_1(z) = \frac 32z(z+1)c_0
$$

etc.